# Creating images when game start get stuck?

Tags: coronasdk

In my game i am creating and transition random building at run-time listener. but that images are too long.when i am creating images it get stuck on my game.how to fix the problem.images are mostly in 15-30 KB.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are too long and go off the screen try using `xScale` and `yScale` to scale the images.  Also remember that images are layered in the order that you place them in your code. For example:

```
display.newImage("image1")
display.newImage("image2")
```

In this example `image2` would be placed about `image1`.

Also keep in mind that if you want to remove images from the screen you have to run this code:

```
image1 = display.newImage("image1.png")
image2 = display.newImage("image2.png")


display.remove(image1)
display.remove(image2)
```

In a runtime listener, you have to make sure to remove the image every frame:

```
local function func1()
    if image1 then display.remove(image1) end
    image1 = display.newImage("image1.png")
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", func1)
```